# How to make jQuery functions run in order when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `.click()` function that performs certain actions when a button is clicked. I want it to display a loading image, run some "stuff", then delete the loading image when the "stuff" is done.

Example of Javascript code:

```
$("#button").click(
function(){
    shoeLoadingImage();
    /**************************************************************************
    *
    * other actions to be performed after showLoadingImage() is finished
    *
    **************************************************************************/
    //Whats below should only to be triggered after above actions above are finished
    hideLoadingImage();
}
 );
```

By using a couple of suggestions here I came up with a solution. It works, but I'm sure there is a better way to do this since my loading.gif is frozen when it is loaded. FYI: the other actions listed under `success: function(){}` contains some actions that take some time to complete which is the whole purpose of this loading image.

```
$("#highlight").click(
function(){
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(){ showLoadingImage(); },
        success: function(){
           /**************************************************************************
    *
    * other actions to be performed after showLoadingImage() is finished
    *
    **************************************************************************/

        },
        complete: function (){ hideLoadingImage(); }
    });
});
```

Comment: What you have should work fine .. it just won't be very effective if the code between show/hide executes very quickly.  Is it an ajax request?

Comment: no ajax request. I added the show and hide functions to be more clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is no ajax call involved your code looks good. Otherwise if showLoadingImage is an ajax call you should do

```
$("#button").click(
function(){
    showLoadingImage();

);

var showLoadingImage = function(){
    $.ajax({
         success: function(){
         /**************************************************************************
         *
         * other actions to be performed after showLoadingImage() is finished
         *
         **************************************************************************/
         hideLoadingImage(); //only to be triggered after above actions are finished
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. There is no ajax call. I added the show and hide functions to be more clear.

Comment: @amlane86 i don't understand what's not working in there, can you provide an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I used your suggestion and added a `beforeSend` and `complete` to the `$.ajax()` and got it working. I posted it above to show you. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are making async calls within the showLoading function, this should work fine. If not, then you need to do a callback in your showLoadingImage which will call hideLoadingImage().

Comment: not true, test in dif browsers, namely chrome and safari, and you will never see an image change using the code that's given till after all other code is run